# What am I doing wrong in the font preload code?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, preload, google-font-api

`<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,600,700&#038;display=swap&#038;ver=1683214000" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,600,700&#038;display=swap&#038;ver=1683214000" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,600,700&#038;display=swap&#038;ver=1683214000" /></noscript><link rel="stylesheet" id="google-fonts-1-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&#038;display=auto&#038;subset=latin-ext&#038;ver=6.2" type="text/css" media="all" />`

This is the preload code I'm using, but I'm getting an error that could not be verified in Search Console. I don't understand if I missed something in the code. Thanx